# Graphic editor for creating pools drawing

Tags: editor, graphic

I need to find graphic editor, which can create simple swimming pools drawing like this: http://k.min.us/iiPZI.png

It must be able to draw pool outline (including curves, not only lines), split pool into several parts (the darker color is - the deaper poll is in this area), also user should be able to provide depth for each area.

Also will be nice, if this editor can calculate pool square (S), perimeter (P), it's scope (V) and square of all walls and bottom (to know how much tile we`ll need).

Please, give me links to any editors, which contain even several of these functionalities, so I can try and upgrade editor for my needs.

You can give links on editors, written on any language/platform (Javascript, standalone programm, etc.). I will need to calculate all this staff (V, P, S, etc.) and then just send this data to PHP (and make calculations on server side).

I found only this editor, but it doesn't have a lot of functionality I need: http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess any good vector editor might do but not sure about the calculations. This might be more a job for an architecture program. You might want to take a look at [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)